# How would you send a mail through mandrill with phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, mandrill

I'm doing some screen scraping with phantomjs. I'm trying to implement an error handling system that sends an email with the mandrill api https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html when the scraper fails.

The mandrill api takes a post method like the one below.
How would you send a mail through mandrill with phantomjs?

```
var data = {
    "key": "VdFwNvj-dLwaI6caAh8ODg",
    "message": {
        "html": "This aggression will not stand",
        "text": "This aggression will not stand",
        "subject": "example subject",
        "from_email": "the-dude@gmail.com",
        "from_name": "The Dude",
        "to": [{
            "email": "lebowski@gmail.com",
            "name": "lebowski"
        }]
    },
    "async": false
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',
    data: data
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I spent some time trying to get the answer working with no joy. I ended up testing with: http://httpbin.org/post to find out why mandril was failing to handle my requests and it turned out that the data wasn't being sent properly. The PhantomJS docs weren't correct either. It was this example: https://github.com/adrianchung/phantomjs/blob/069ab5dea4c07c61a0ac259df0ff219ade1e8225/examples/postjson.js that ended up giving me the missing piece. The mandrill docs were also very useful: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html

My completed code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var email_url = 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json';
//email_url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'; // When testing

var email_data = {
    key: "your-key",
    "message": {
        "text": email_message_text,
        "subject": "Your subject",
        "from_email": "your email",
        "from_name": "Kris",
        "to": [{
            "email": "your email",
            "name": "Kris"
        }]
    },
    "async": false
};
var email_headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
};

page.open(
    email_url, 
    'post', 
    JSON.stringify(email_data), // You need to stringify the json or it doesn't work
    email_headers, 
    function (status) {

        if (status !== 'success') {
            PrintError('FAIL to email results');
        } else {        
            var result = page.evaluate(function () {
                        return document.body.innerText;
                    });
            Print('Email successfully sent\n' + result);
        }       
        phantom.exit();
     }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to spin up a new page to make a RESTful call, then you can use page.evaluate to read the result. While it is not as simple as the jQuery ajax method, you could easily create object to simplify its use.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    url = 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',
    data = {
    "key": "VdFwNvj-dLwaI6caAh8ODg",
    "message": {
        "html": "This aggression will not stand",
        "text": "This aggression will not stand",
        "subject": "example subject",
        "from_email": "the-dude@gmail.com",
        "from_name": "The Dude",
        "to": [{
            "email": "lebowski@gmail.com",
            "name": "lebowski"
        }]
    },
    "async": false
};

page.open(url, 'POST', data, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('FAIL to load the log');
    } else {
        console.log('Log success');

        var result = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.body.innerText;
        });

        console.log("log Result: " + result);
    }       
});
```